# How to change title of 'untitled' with PDF embed tag in HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a portfolio page of old articles I wrote and saved as PDF.

http://elksie5000.pythonanywhere.com/articles

Frustratingly the title is 'untitled'.

Is there a simple way to change the title to something more useful?

Here's the code for the embed tag I used. (I know it should be relative)

```
<embed src="http://elksie5000.pythonanywhere.com/static/Renew1.pdf" width="100%" height="1250"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add your title inside html title tag `<title>My PDF title</title>` when you are generate the PDF file.. title is part of the pdf file.

Comment: It will have multiple PDFs. Can I insert that into the embed tag?

Comment: You can't change the title using embed code you should change it wile genereate the pdf  file..